# Unable to run Playwright "Writing Assertions" example

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, playwright, playwright-test

## TL;DR

Can't get "Writing Assertions" example from [Playwright Getting Started](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro) page to work.

## Full Story

I'm looking at [Playwright](https://playwright.dev) for writing tests. I'm working my way through the [Getting Started](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro) examples, and am having an issue with **Example #2 (Writing Assertions)**. I'm doing this on my work machine (macOS) and haven't had the opportunity to try it from my Linux machine at home yet, if that makes a difference.

The example in question is:

```js
// example.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('my test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle('Playwright');

  // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
  await expect(page.locator('text=Get Started')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');

  // Expect an element "to be visible".
  await expect(page.locator('text=Learn more')).toBeVisible();

  await page.click('text=Get Started');
  // Expect some text to be visible on the page.
  await expect(page.locator('text=System requirements')).toBeVisible();

  // Compare screenshot with a stored reference.
  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('get-started.png');
});
```

The initial issue I had was with this line failing:

```js
await expect(page).toHaveTitle('Playwright');
```

I was able to resolve it by changing the `.toHaveTitle()` to look for a regex, so now it looks like the following:

```js
// 02_writing_assertions.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('my test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);  // Updated to regex

  // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
  await expect(page.locator('text=Get Started')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');

  // Expect an element "to be visible".
  await expect(page.locator('text=Learn more')).toBeVisible();

  await page.click('text=Get Started');

  // Expect some text to be visible on the page.
  await expect(page.locator('text=System requirements')).toBeVisible();

  // Compare screenshot with a stored reference.
  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('get-started.png');
});
```

However, when I run it, I now get the following:

```sh
❯ npx playwright test tests/getting_started/02_writing_assertions.spec.js --headed

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✘  tests/getting_started/02_writing_assertions.spec.js:4:1 › my test (4s)


  1) tests/getting_started/02_writing_assertions.spec.js:4:1 › my test =============================

    locator.getAttribute: Evaluation failed: Error: strict mode violation: selector resolved to 2 elements.
        at u.querySelector (<anonymous>:3:34807)
        at eval (eval at evaluate (:3:1339), <anonymous>:7:32)
        at i (<anonymous>:3:37685)
        at <anonymous>:3:37773
        at Object.run (<anonymous>:3:38253)
        at eval (eval at evaluate (:3:1339), <anonymous>:1:14)
        at t.default.evaluate (<anonymous>:3:1362)
        at t.default.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)
    =========================== logs ===========================
      retrieving attribute "href" from "text=Get Started"
      strict mode violation: selector resolved to 2 elements.
    ============================================================

       9 |
      10 |   // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
    > 11 |   await expect(page.locator('text=Get Started')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');
         |                                                  ^
      12 |
      13 |   // Expect an element "to be visible".
      14 |   await expect(page.locator('text=Learn more')).toBeVisible();

        at /Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/matchers/matchers.js:131:27
        at /Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/matchers/toMatchText.js:48:22
        at pollUntilDeadline (/Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/util.js:119:42)
        at Object.toMatchText (/Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/matchers/toMatchText.js:47:37)
        at Object.toHaveAttribute (/Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/matchers/matchers.js:130:35)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/expect.js:94:30)
        at __EXTERNAL_MATCHER_TRAP__ (/Users/me/node_modules/expect/build/index.js:342:30)
        at Object.throwingMatcher (/Users/me/node_modules/expect/build/index.js:343:15)
        at /Users/me/dev/playwright/playwright-test/tests/getting_started/02_writing_assertions.spec.js:11:50
        at WorkerRunner._runTestWithBeforeHooks (/Users/me/node_modules/@playwright/test/lib/test/workerRunner.js:425:7)


  1 failed
    tests/getting_started/02_writing_assertions.spec.js:4:1 › my test ==============================
```

Commenting out each of the `await expect(...)` statements simply repeats the error at the next `await expect(...)` statement. If I comment out all of them, then the `await page.click(...)` runs as expected, but the next `await expect(...)` fails again.

### Update

So...it appears that the issue is that the issue is that the `page.locator(...)` as written is returning multiple elements, which should've been immediately obvious by the fact that I'm seeing the following error:

> Evaluation failed: Error: strict mode violation: selector resolved to 2 elements.

So I changed the following line:

```js
await expect(page.locator('text=Get Started')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');
```

to

```js
await expect(page.locator('//a[text()="Get Started"][1]')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');
```

which I thought would've resolved the issue. However, now I'm getting a timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work my way through (almost) all the issues. The one issue with the initial script that I haven't been able to resolve yet is this line:

```js
// Expect some text to be visible on the page.
await expect(page.locator('text=System requirements')).toBeVisible();
```

This string appears twice on the page. In attempting various ways to search the string (i.e., `xpath`), my code either returned both elements or timed out. Since this was an arbitrary string on the page, rather than an element that needed to be clicked in order to proceed to the next step, I simply substituted a different string.

The working script is as follows:

```js
// 02_writing_assertions.spec.js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');

test('my test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://playwright.dev/');

  // Expect a title "to contain" a substring.
  await expect(page).toHaveTitle(/Playwright/);

  // Expect an attribute "to be strictly equal" to the value.
  await expect(page.locator('(//a[translate(text(),"get started","GET STARTED")="GET STARTED"])[1]')).toHaveAttribute('href', '/docs/intro');

  // Expect an element "to be visible".
  await expect(page.locator('(//a[translate(text(),"learn more", "LEARN MORE")="LEARN MORE"])[1]')).toBeVisible();

  // Click "Get Started"
  await page.click('(//a[translate(text(),"get started","GET STARTED")="GET STARTED"])[1]')

  // Expect some text to be visible on the page.
  await expect(page.locator('(//h1[contains(translate(text(),"getting started","GETTING STARTED"),"GETTING STARTED")])[1]')).toBeVisible()

  // Compare screenshot with a stored reference.
  expect(await page.screenshot()).toMatchSnapshot('get-started.png');
});
```

A few items about my `xpath` statements:

- I always translate my text strings to upper-case for comparison, just to harden the test against a future typo that turns "Get Started" into "GEt Started".
- The same with always referencing the `xpath` return set by specific element; it hardens against a second instance of the same URL being added by someone in the future.